# Processing a string into JNI layer by passing through java API and creating a buffer using malloc

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am working on an java API which will be used to process a string in cpp and return a processed string.

The Cpp code in the jni I am using is mentioned below

```
char * buffer;
static
void process(char *str, int shift) {
    // some processing 
}
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_process (
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject,
        jstring string,
        jint shift) {
    const char *key = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, nullptr);
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(key));

    strcpy(buffer, key);

    char *p = buffer;
    process(buffer, shift);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, key);
    return env->NewStringUTF(p);

}
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_freeN (
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject) {
    free(buffer);
    buffer = nullptr;
}
```

**Java API**

```
fun processStr(string: String): String {

            val str = process(string, 10)
            freeN()
            return str
        }
```

**Couple of points to note here:**

**1.** Since the string passed from java to C using JNI, it is received as const, I cannot do any operation, so buffer is created and using strcpy to copy and then manipulating the string

**2.** Calling freeN() from java code itself, to free the allocated buffer.

**3.** There could be another approach of passing java's ByteBuffer from java then using the buffer in JNI This way freeing memory wont be an issue?

are these a right approach to go about this ? What could be better approach? How i can make it thread safe ?
Do you think calling this java API asynchronously is a good idea or API should be synchronised ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not figure out from your question whether `process` relies on its input being null terminated, but note that this is not required by the specification. I also could not figure out what the shape of `process`' inputs and outputs should be. If you are going to pass in or out arbitrary data, that should be a Java `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer`, **not** a java.lang.String.

`env->NewStringUTF(p)` allocates a new Java string whose memory is managed by Java.
Once the string has been allocated you can already safely free `buffer`.

Second, by storing `buffer` globally, you made your function not reentrant and you made your life harder. Imagine what happens if two threads call into `Java_com_example_process` simultaneously.

Finally, `sizeof(key)` returns the size of the *pointer*, not the thing it points to. So this will fail horribly if your string goes beyond 4 or 8 bytes (depending on architecture). Luckily, you can simply ask the JNI what your string length will be.

I suggest the following rewrite, where the JVM is responsible for disposing of the returned string so you do not have to call `freeN` anymore.

```
static void process(const char *in, char *out, int shift) {
    // some processing where you take data from `in` and write to `out`
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_process (
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject,
        jstring string,
        jint shift) {
    jsize key_size = env->GetStringUTFLength(string);
    const char *key = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, nullptr);

    char * buffer = new char[key_size];
    process(key, buffer, shift);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, key);
    jstring ret = env->NewStringUTF(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Few correction, ret will be jstring not jobject and also there should be null check for buffer right ?
Btw you solution looks cleaner to me. Thanks

Comment: `new` never returns a null pointer, and jstring is a subtype of jobject.

Comment: what the difference between  env->GetStringUTFLength(string) and strlen(key) ?

Comment: The former is correct in the presence of NUL bytes and potentially known up front by the JVM.

Comment: I am trying 
strlcpy(buffer, key, key_size) its is wrong and strlcpy(buffer, key, key_size+1) it is correctly passing my unit test which i have written, any thought how this occuring ?

Comment: do you think both return the same value ?

Comment: From the strlcpy man page: "`strlcpy()` takes the **full size** of the destination buffer and guarantee NUL-termination if there is room.  **Note that room for the NUL should be included in `dstsize`."**

Comment: so dont you think buffer should be
char * buffer = new char[key_size + 1] ?

Comment: As I said, that depends on `process` and whether it does null-termination.

Comment: if process just simply does
`strlcpy(buffer, key, key_size)` ? 
then we should do this
`jsize key_size = env->GetStringUTFLength(string) + 1`; is this correct ?

Comment: I think so, yes.